# how to create image slider in laravel with css or jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel-5

new to Lalavel. using 5.2 and need create simple scrolling image slider with css or jquery/ js I need some guide line or consult. tutorial site is ok

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For simple slider I will recommend [Owl Carousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)
Using of it is described on its page.

To build structure for it just select images from database, disk, or just build own array of images, then display them with simple blade foreach loop:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    @foreach ($images as $image)
        <div class="item">
            <img src="{{ $image }}">
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need autoplay slider examples

Comment: Look at options of owlcarousel. Autoplay is enabled by defaut